# How do I listen to OneNote Interop events (15.0 library) from unmanaged code?

Tags: events, interop, office-interop, unmanaged, onenote

I wrote a C# WPF app that can read/write/update to my OneNote application, using the OneNote 2013 APIs from [this guidance from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg649853(v=office.14).aspx).

But when I tried to register to the OnNavigate event, nothing happened, and the event handling methods never got executed!  When I read further into the above guidance, I found that Microsoft specifically stated that ["Events currently cannot be added in managed code"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg649853(v=office.14).aspx#ON14DevRef_Application_Events).

So what does this mean, actually?  Does this mean that there *is* a solution, but I'd have to write the solution myself in C++ unmanaged code?  If so, how would I go about doing something like this to expose the events and consume them in my C# WPF app?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this link will be useful for you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/descapa/archive/2007/02/06/creating-a-c-c-add-in-which-works-with-onenote.aspx

Comment: Btw, did you solve your issue? If so, please answer the question for yourself, I'm interested.

Comment: Haven't resolved it yet, but I did get some guidance in Microsoft's developer community (it requires a Live account to read): https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6db22fd7-9203-45e5-bbbf-d6d105ca5f72/how-do-i-listen-to-onenote-interop-events-150-library-from-unmanaged-code?forum=officegeneral  I plan to try it out sometime, and in which case I will update this question with my results.  No ETA.

Comment: Is there anything new?

Comment: @AndreyAnt because of the limited scope of my project from five years ago, we did not pursue this solution further and the idea was scrapped.  Hopefully, you have enough information in the comments to gain some ground on your own. Best regards, Tam.